# ProgrammingError at /api/accounts/ relation does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have this django app on windows 10

- python 3.6.2
- django 1.11.5
- djangorest 3.6.4
- postgreSql 9.6

I'm using a **custom User Model(AppUser)** in the accounts app and i have **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.AppUser'** in my settings file.

I migrate in this order as advised from various sources

1. `migrate auth`
2. `migrate accounts`
3. `migrate` to migrate all other apps

And migrations succeeds as expected. The problem begins when i try to access the api through the browsable api

> ProgrammingError at /api/accounts/
>   relation "accounts_appuser" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "accounts_appuser" WHERE "

I've delete all `.pyc` files created migrations again and got the same error. Through the process of trying over and over sometimes migration reports

> No migrations to apply

Im starting to think the problem is from postgre

Comment: simple solution drop and create database - can you?

Comment: i have done that 1000 times still

Comment: show your settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS`, `DATABASES`, command you use to drop database, `urls`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41652951

Answer (score 4):

The error there is saying that the database table for the AppUser model in the accounts app doesn't exist.

I think the problem here might be that you [haven't run the `makemigrations` mgmt command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) on the accounts app to create the migration, that will in turn create the database table. For example:

```
python manage.py makemigrations accounts
```

You might want to run `makemigrations` for the whole app too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of things but am not sure which one worked

first i re-installed postgre

them apply migrations manually in this order, auth, account, then all the other in the installed app one after the other

then i tried the browesable api and its working.

I also realized that you have to keep your settings file even if you are not using it

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had similar problem. The reason was I forget the register my app to the settings.py. If You forget register your application, make migrations and migrate does not recognize any error. And you receive message

```
No migrations to apply
```

Be sure you registered your app to the settings.file INSTALLED APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 -----HERE----
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you run these two commands just to be certain,

> 1. python manage.py makemigrations

then

> 2. python manage.py makemigrations [name_of_app]

Hereafter, run the migrate app, that way your application creates migrations for all you project and app.