# Unable to access existing table of database added in Django Admin portal

Tags: postgresql, python, django

I am trying to "bring in" an existing PostgreSQL into Django. I did the following:

1. Added a stanza for my existing DB in settings.py under default.
2. Executed: `# python manage.py migrate --database=carddb`
3. `# python manage.py inspectdb --database=carddb >> ./myapp/models.py`

At this point I can see PostgreSQL built-in's & cardb's table updated in models.py.

4. `#python manage.py makemigrations myapp`
5. `#python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001`
6. `#python manage.py migrate`
7. Created superuser for admin site and updated admin.py to include carddb's table

   8. `# python manage.py runserver`

Although I can see the table, but as soon as I click, django admin portal throws this:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "cardtable" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "cardtable"

I have already checked and found that "case" discrepancy is not a problem. Please can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably better suited for stackoverflow (and there are already votes to migrate) but I think you should post your models file generated by the the inspectdb

Comment: Hi Tom, apart from Django's built in I have only one class imported into models.py:
class Acardtable(models.Model):          
    region = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    card = JSONField()                         

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'acardtable'

In addition to that I'd like to show me project's settings file:

Comment: In addition to that I'd like to show me project's settings file. I am using two databases. 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mysitedb',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',

    },

    'acarddb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'acarddb',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

Comment: Although I have a default database, but I wish to use acarddb database and therefore included that in "admin.py" to check whether I can update the fields in admin portal.
admin.py:
from .models import Acardtable
admin.site.register(Acardtable)

Looks like, I have made a silly mistake by not keeping "acarddb" as default. forgive me, I am a novice anything you can point out here will be of great help as I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem by following steps mentioned in:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41652951