# Relation does not exist in django admin site after migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm getting a "relation does not exist error" when attempting to access a model page on my django admin site. Accessing the user model from the admin site works normally.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/web_app/work/

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'web_app.apps.WebsiteConfig',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "web_app_work" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "web_app_work"
                                          ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1570.             cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_changelist_instance
  705.             self,

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in __init__
  77.         self.get_results(request)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in get_results
  175.         result_count = paginator.count

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  36.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py" in count
  85.             return self.object_list.count()

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in count
  387.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_count
  491.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_aggregation
  476.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1067.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\danie\Envs\Prolitfic\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/web_app/work/
Exception Value: relation "web_app_work" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "web_app_work"
```

Here is my model:

```py
class Work(models.Model):
    work_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    writer_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Writer,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null = True,
        verbose_name = "Author")
    content = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_ratings = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Number of Ratings", default=0)
    ratings_sum = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Sum of Ratings", default=0)
    ratings_avg = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Rating Score", default=0)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reversed('story', args=[str(self.work_id)])

    def __string__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my migration file:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comment',
            fields=[
                ('text', models.TextField()),
                ('ratings_sum', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Sum of Ratings')),
                ('num_ratings', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Number of Ratings')),
                ('ratings_avg', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Rating Score')),
                ('date_created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('comment_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Work',
            fields=[
                ('work_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('views', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('num_ratings', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Number of Ratings')),
                ('ratings_sum', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Sum of Ratings')),
                ('ratings_avg', models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Rating Score')),
                ('date_created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('read_count', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Writer',
            fields=[
                ('writer_id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('writer_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='work',
            name='writer_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='web_app.Writer', verbose_name='Author'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='work_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='web_app.Work'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='writer_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='web_app.Writer', verbose_name='Commenter'),
        ),
    ]
```

Things I've already tried:

- Migrating individual apps
- Migrating from scratch(deleting all migrations and pycache of web_app and migrations folders)
- Changing the work model
- Commenting out the urls and views, migrating, then uncommenting them

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41652951

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed my issue by following the steps listed in this guide:

https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-initial-django-migrations-for-existing-schema/

Step1: Empty the django_migrations table:

Just go to your corresponding database terminals and delete all the records from you django_migrations table with

```
delete from django_migrations;
```

Step2: Remove all the files in migrations folders in each and every app of your project.

Go to terminal and run remove all files in migrations folder with

```
rm -rf <app>/migrations/
```

Step3: Reset the migrations for the "built-in" apps:

Reset all the migrations of the Django's built-in apps like admin with the command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Step4: Create initial migrations for each and every app:

For each app run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app>.
```

Note: Take care of dependencies (models with ForeignKey's should run after their parent model).

Step5: Final step is to create fake initial migrations:

To create initial fake migrations just run

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

After the above steps I was able to run makemigrations and migrate normally.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20036416)

Comment: Thanks, I added the steps in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, once I got the same problem and for solving that I deleted all migrations and pycache of that app except **init**.py 
This happened because your makemigrations command worked properly but your migrate doesn't migrate any thing.

Comment: I already tried this and got the same error, I'll edit my post so that "migrating from scratch" is clearer

Comment: Are you having populated data ?

Comment: There's no data populated in the table, is that necessary to view that part of the admin site? I figured it would just show an empty list.

Comment: No, tell me when you migrate from scratch, what do you see - applying migrations... or no migrations applied ?

Comment: Have you tried migrate --fake, makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: umm, this happened to me also, unfortunately nothing worked, I don't know the best way but I can tell you what I did, drop my db and create new, start new project with different name and apps, copy all files except migrations and then migrate again. Remember if you do this please make sure to have a different project name! good luck