# Relation does not exist - Django & Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-models

I added some table to an existant model, but I got an **error** when i push my project to heroku :

This happens to any models I add on this particular app

> ProgrammingError at /admin/dashboard/adressbook/
>   relation "dashboard_adressbook" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "dashboard_adressbook"

**My models.py**

```
class AdressBook(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Description")
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="Numéro de téléphone")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home')  

class Dashboard(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    content = RichTextField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Description")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home')

class Links(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    content = models.URLField(max_length=500, verbose_name="URL")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home') 

class Todo(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nom de la Todo")
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Description supplémentaire",null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Statut de la Todo")
    urgence = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="Tâche urgente")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home') 

class Phone(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Nom de l'utilisateur")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Description")
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="Numéro de téléphone")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home')
```

**Traceback :**

```
   Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['blog.apps.BlogConfig',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'property.apps.PropertyConfig',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'cloudinary',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "dashboard_adressbook" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "dashboard_adressbook"
                                          ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  604.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1675.             cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_changelist_instance
  742.             sortable_by,

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  81.         self.get_results(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_results
  209.         result_count = paginator.count

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  37.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  87.             return self.object_list.count()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  383.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  498.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  483.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1065.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/dashboard/adressbook/
Exception Value: relation "dashboard_adressbook" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "dashboard_adressbook"
                                          ^
```

I did all of my migrations on my local machine but stil the problem does not go away.

I did my migrations on Heroku as well.

Thanks

Comment: But did you run the migrations on Heroku?

Comment: Yes ! I did it over and over and nothing change

Comment: Please show exactly what you did.

Comment: Dude, this is a debug request, not a question. Stop repeating it - there is no direct answer on it. My guess is that you made some migrations locally, then added some code which is being executed "before everything" and is referring the new model. Locally it is running fine but on remote you don't have those migrations applied and this code fails "before everything". Try clean build locally. And on Postgres, of course.

Comment: I added to my model.py an Addressbook table, then I run the migration, it got add so I push my project to heroku and it said "no changes detected"

Comment: @IvanStarostin The purpose of SO is to ask question and get answers right ? If this case no one found an anwser and if some people are on the same situation I believe they will like to get an anwser.
I did a clean build I even delete some models but that does not solve anything

Comment: Such a question is called "offtopic: why is this code not working?" on SO.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Alright I will try to do a clean app then, thanks anyway !

Comment: (a) Are you still trying to use MySQL locally and PostgreSQL on Heroku, as you mentioned in your previous two (now deleted) questions? That's just as terrible an idea now as it was then. (b) Are you sure your migrations actually work? I.e., are you sure that your current Heroku database is in a state given by a set of existing migrations *and* can you run migrations locally from that precise state?

Comment: @Chris Hello : As I said below, I started clean, I realize that was an huge mistake and will edit my answer accordinely so no one will do the same because there were no fix for that

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41652951

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warning :** **Please do not make the same mistake, do not use a different engine on on your local machine and on production, once you encounter a problem, it is impossible to fix it**

So after 4 days I solved this problem by deleting the data from my Database.

I started **clean** and I made sure to **migrate before** the push to heroku, I have also been using the **same engine** (postgres) on my local machine and Heroku and I haven't encounter any bug so far.

So to solve this problem you have to start clean, the only solution is to delete the database, which is not convenient if you have valuable data.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

1. heroku run bash
2. python manage.py makemigrations
3. python manage.py migrate

Comment: No, _don't_ run `makemigrations` on Heroku. There is never any reason to do this. By the time your code is deployed, all migrations should have been generated and committed locally. Only run `migrate` on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when landing on a template getting data from my database, after having resetted my database from Heroku dashboard.

I solved it by doing:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate
3. git add .
4. git push -m "upload empty database"
5. git push heroku master

Comment: Hi ! 
Yes, to solve this problem we have to start clean, but then again, the only solution is to delete the database, which is not convenient if you have valuable data