# Relation does not exist behavior in django + postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

After looking at all the other answers here I still can't figure this out. In my project I have two apps, the first app `users` manages users and the second one `signals` manages the contents to be displayed. Right now I am just trying to make the second app `signals` work but even the simplest models will throw errors in `admin`.

The error i get:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/signals/signal/
relation "signals_signal" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "signals_signal"
```

This is what I have in `models.py`:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.ticker)

class Signal(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

In `settings.py`;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'users',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

And the `admin.py` for `signals` is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Asset, Signal

# Register your models here.
class AssetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Asset, AssetAdmin)

class SignalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Signal, SignalAdmin)
```

I have tried basically everything: deleting migrations, doing `startapp` from scratch etc. I have never used postgres before. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Are both apps included in your main settings file? Do you see the migrations file for the `Asset` and `Signal` models inside your signals app? The error you see means that the `signals_signal` table doesn't exist in your database, so that indicates that you didn't create/run the migrations.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten yes, they are both In the settings. And I do have a migrations folder. However even if I delete all migrations and rerun makemigrations and migrate I get the same problem

Comment: you can use `psql` command-line tool to inspect your database and check which tables are created in your db. Also check the `django_migrations` table, the rows tell you which migrations were run.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41652951

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem came from the invalid `ENGINE` configuration in the settings.

Change this

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        ...  other configurations
    }
}
```

to

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        ...  other configurations
    }
}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#engine